# Is there a way to measure the entire data usage (wifi/mobile-data) of the app during the session?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to measure how much data the app uses during the session. For example, open the app -> use it for some time -> check how much data has been consumed (eg: entire data usage - 150Mb).

I see there is some info in the network profiler, like how much data has been consumed by each query (in/out), however, there is no "entire usage" value.

Are there any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You can measure the data usage of an app during a session programmatically in Android using Kotlin. Android provides the TrafficStats class, which allows you to monitor the network traffic statistics for your app. You can use this class to measure the data usage of both Wi-Fi and mobile data.

Here's an example of how you can use TrafficStats to measure data usage:

```
import android.net.TrafficStats

// Start measuring data usage
val initialTxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()
val initialRxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()

// Perform your app operations here

// End measuring data usage
val finalTxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()
val finalRxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()

// Calculate the data usage
val totalTxBytes = finalTxBytes - initialTxBytes
val totalRxBytes = finalRxBytes - initialRxBytes
val totalBytes = totalTxBytes + totalRxBytes

// Convert bytes to a human-readable format (e.g., MB, GB)
val formattedTotalBytes = 
android.text.format.Formatter.formatFileSize(context, totalBytes)

// Print or display the total data usage
Log.d("Data Usage", "Total Data Usage: $formattedTotalBytes")
```

In this example, we first capture the initial number of transmitted (`initialTxBytes`) and received (`initialRxBytes`) bytes using `TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()` and `TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()`, respectively. Then, after performing your app operations, you capture the final transmitted and received bytes (`finalTxBytes` and `finalRxBytes`). Finally, you calculate the total data usage by subtracting the initial values from the final values.

Note that you need to make sure you have the necessary permissions in your app's manifest file to access network state:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Additionally, keep in mind that TrafficStats measures the cumulative network traffic since the device was last booted. If you want to measure the data usage specifically during your app session, you should reset the values of TrafficStats at the start of your session by calling `TrafficStats.clearThreadStatsTag()`.

Comment: Actually, I can see this statistic in `network inspector`. The problem is that it is not shown in the `network inspector` "entire" data usage, but only for each query. So, it is very similar to what you suggested in your answer.

Comment: This is the simple type of solution I added here as an example, you can modify it as you want and do the `// End measuring data usage` and `// Calculate the data usage` whenever you need to calculate all the traffic during a custom timespan, this way the session that you want to calculate is up to you when you end the measuring data usage